# Changing lftp log location in the middle of transfer

Tags: bash, ftp, lftp

I am trying to tranfer multiple file using lftp 4.4.8 on a centos 7 machine, on a daily basis.

For the purpose of monitoring this workflow, I would like to log transferred file into 2 groups (`first` and `second`). So I change the log file address in the middle of transfer script, using `set xfer:logfile mysecond.txt`.

Here is the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

lftp $HOST -u $USER,$PASSWORD <<EOF

set xfer:log true
set xfer:log-file myfirst.log

lcd /local/path/first

cd /remote/path/first

put file-first.txt
put file-first2.txt

lcd /local/path/second
set xfer:log-file mysecond.log

cd /remote/path/second

put file-second.txt
put file-second2.txt

bye
EOF
```

But the result is not as expected. All transferred file (including `file-second.txt` and `file-second2.txt`) are logged into the first log file (`myfirst.log`). Looks like lftp does not recognize changing the log file in the following line:

```sh
set xfer:log-file mysecond.log
```

Am I missing something? How can I achieve what I intend?

Many thanks.

Comment: i think it is an issue, you may search in https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues

Comment: Changing the log file works for me with lftp version 4.8.4 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks @OliverGaida. I already did, and created as [issue](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/607) myself since couldn't find anything in previous ones.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, I thought so. Unfortunately the latest packaged version for Centos 7 is 4.4.8, and I am trying to avoid the hassle of installing from source, etc.

Comment: I have just tested it with lftp version 4.4.8 and RHEL 7. I can confirm that it does not work with this version.